# Pass JSON object to table with Javascript, at a loss

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I am trying to pass a json array object from my server to my page as a Table for a homework assignment. I can't get the loop to work.

I tried a loop that created a bunch of empty tables in the console. Something is definitely wrong.
the JSON array is:

```
{
    "degrees":[
        {
            "degree":{
                "School": "Dutchess Community College",
                "Program": "Humanities",
                "Type": "Associate of Arts",
                "Year": "2009"
            }
        },
        {
            "degree":{
                "School": "Binghamton University",
                "Program": "English Literature",
                "Type": "Bachelor of Arts",
                "Year": "2011"
```

ETC.

The desired output is a simple table, so:

```
       School    |     Program      |    Type                |Year
dutchesscommunity college  Humanities    associate of arts        2009
Binghamton                English Lit    Bachelor of arts         2011
```

```
const getDegrees = () => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', 'data/degrees.json', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( (xhr.readyState === 4) && (xhr.status === 200) ) {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            const table = document.createElement("TABLE");
            table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
            document.body.appendChild(table);


            var degrees = response.degrees;
            var degreeHeaders = Object.keys(degrees[0].degree);    

            var headerRow = document.createElement("TR");
            headerRow.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
            table.appendChild(headerRow);

           for (let i = 0; i < degreeHeaders.length; i++) {
                const headerCell = document.createElement("th");
                headerCell.innerText = degreeHeaders[i]; 
                headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
            }


            for (let i = 0; i < degrees.length; i++) {

                let degreeData = degrees[i].degree;
                let tr = document.createElement("TR");
                table.appendChild(tr);


                for (let column = 0; column < degreeHeaders.length; column++) {
                    const columnProperty = degreeHeaders[column];
                    let td = document.createElement("td");
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.innerHTML = degreeData[columnProperty];
                }
            }
        }

    }
};            
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', getDegrees);
```

ALTERNATELY

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');


const getDegrees = () => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', 'data/degrees.json', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( (xhr.readyState === 4) && (xhr.status === 200) ) {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            function createTr(line, i) {
                var y = document.createElement("TR");
                 y.setAttribute("id", "myTr" + i);
                 var school = document.createElement("TD");
                 school.innerHTML = line['School'];
                 var program = document.createElement("TD");
                 program.innerHTML = line['Program'];
                 var type = document.createElement("TD");
                 type.innerHTML = line['Type'];
                 var year = document.createElement("TD");
                 year.innerHTML = line['Year'];
                 y.appendChild(school);
                 y.appendChild(program);
                 y.appendChild(type);
                 y.appendChild(year);
                 return y;
          }

         function getDegrees() {
             var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
             x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
             document.body.appendChild(x);

             x.append(createTr({"School": "School",
                         "Program": "Program",
                         "Type": "Type",
                         "Year": "Year" }, 0));
             for (var i = 0; i < response['degrees'].length; i++) {
                 var line = response['degrees'][i]['degree'];    
                 var tr = createTr(line, i);
                 x.appendChild(tr);
             }        

         };
        }
    }
}
btn.addEventListener('click', getDegrees);
```

Comment: Please fix this line: `var t = document.createTextNode response += i);`

Comment: @AndrewSteier In that line, you have a closed parenthesis but no open one. Also, you are overwriting the response by assigning the loop index to it.

Comment: To give you a hint: a table consists of multiple rows, and a row consists of multiple cells. Assuming you know how to use developer tools, I highly recommend using `console.log()` to help you debug.

Comment: It looks like you are subscribing to the button click in the wrong scope now.

Could you move `const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        btn.addEventListener('click', getDegrees);` To the bottom (i.e. after all of the braces)

Comment: Yep. No good either.

Comment: You didn't include id attribute. Also querySelector returns an array of objects. Even when it's only one. Include the id attribute and remove the querySelector line and it will work.

Comment: Okay, last issue looks like you are not sending the actual request after setting it up.

Could you add `xhr.send(null);` at the end of your `getDegrees` function

Comment: You are maintaining the querySelector line at the top of the code. Just delete it all together. It's not needed.

Comment: It's what causing btn not to work, because you're applying eventlistener to an array of objects instead of btn

Comment: THAT DID IT (both of you, actually. trying them concurrently.), this has been a very frustrating 18 hours. I'm gonna try and do another one from scratch to make sure I understand.
I really appreciate it. Hopefully I too can one day render such assistance to the newbies.

Comment: Glad it is working :) Good luck with the rest!

Comment: Nice. If it was helpful please upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to get a list of 'column' names based on the properties from the first degree. (This assumes all the degrees will have the same properties as this row)

Create a 'Header Row' and add these properties as "Header Cells".

Then, loop through each of the degrees, add a row for the degree, and add a cell for each of the header columns, with the degrees value for that property.

See an example bellow (It cuts out the request part of you javascript but should behave the same.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Load Data</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDegrees() {
            const response = {
                "degrees": [
                    {
                        "degree": {
                            "School": "Dutchess Community College",
                            "Program": "Humanities",
                            "Type": "Associate of Arts",
                            "Year": "2009"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "degree": {
                            "School": "Binghamton University",
                            "Program": "English Literature",
                            "Type": "Bachelor of Arts",
                            "Year": "2011"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };

            // Create the table
            const table = document.createElement("TABLE");
            table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
            document.body.appendChild(table);

            // Get the firest degree element, and get the headers from it
            var degrees = response.degrees;
            var degreeHeaders = Object.keys(degrees[0].degree); // i.e. this will be an array of ["School", "Program", "Type" "Year"]

            // Create a row for the headers
            var headerRow = document.createElement("TR");
            headerRow.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
            table.appendChild(headerRow);

            // Add a cell for each of the 'columns' based on the properties that we will display
            for (let i = 0; i < degreeHeaders.length; i++) {
                const headerCell = document.createElement("th");
                headerCell.innerText = degreeHeaders[i]; 
                headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
            }

            // Loop over each of the degree elements
            for (let i = 0; i < degrees.length; i++) {

                // Build a row element and add it to the table
                let degreeData = degrees[i].degree;
                let tr = document.createElement("TR");
                table.appendChild(tr);

                // For each 'Header' property, build a cell and add it to the current degree's row
                for (let column = 0; column < degreeHeaders.length; column++) {
                    const columnProperty = degreeHeaders[column]; // This is the propery for the column i.e.  ["School", "Program", "Type" "Year"]
                    let td = document.createElement("td");
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.innerHTML = degreeData[columnProperty];
                }
            }
        }
        const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        btn.addEventListener('click', getDegrees);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I feel dumb. I can't get this to work, even though the snippet works fine here.

Comment: There is nothing to feel dump about! We all start somewhere. Do you get an error in the browser javascript console (Pressing F12 in your browser should bring this up)?

Comment: nope. no errors. just does nothing on click. I know the HTML is ok because I was able to get individual values from the array to show up, but I lose it when I try to make the table happen.

Comment: visible now in original post.

Comment: It looks like you are subscribing to the button click in the wrong scope now.

Could you move `const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        btn.addEventListener('click', getDegrees);` To the end of the bottom (i.e. after all of the braces)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for what you want:

```js
var json = {
    "degrees":[
        {
            "degree":{
                "School": "Dutchess Community College",
                "Program": "Humanities",
                "Type": "Associate of Arts",
                "Year": "2009"
            }
        },
        {
            "degree":{
                "School": "Binghamton University",
                "Program": "English Literature",
                "Type": "Bachelor of Arts",
                "Year": "2011"
           }
        } ]
};

function createTr(line, i) {
       var y = document.createElement("TR");
        y.setAttribute("id", "myTr" + i);
        var school = document.createElement("TD");
        school.innerHTML = line['School'];
        var program = document.createElement("TD");
        program.innerHTML = line['Program'];
        var type = document.createElement("TD");
        type.innerHTML = line['Type'];
        var year = document.createElement("TD");
        year.innerHTML = line['Year'];
        y.appendChild(school);
        y.appendChild(program);
        y.appendChild(type);
        y.appendChild(year);
        return y;
 }

function getDegrees() {
    var response = json;
    var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    x.append(createTr({"School": "School",
                "Program": "Program",
                "Type": "Type",
                "Year": "Year" }, 0));
    for (var i = 0; i < response['degrees'].length; i++) {
        var line = response['degrees'][i]['degree'];    
        var tr = createTr(line, i);
        x.appendChild(tr);
    }        
    
};

btn.addEventListener('click', getDegrees);
```

```html
<div id='res'>
</div>
<button id="btn" >Get Degrees</button>
```

Comment: I added the div class to my html, button shows up etc. but I can't get the script to run on button press. No errors in the console, either.

Comment: Do you included the `id="btn"` attribute in the button?

Comment: If yes include the new code in the question and I'll try to help you more.

Comment: So does that not go in the HTML? I was under the impression that it did ( I have them in separate pages.)